# jquery not this selector for a tags not working

Tags: jquery, this, href

I'm having trouble with a very simple jquery function. 
Somehow I'm not able to define "other" correctly, so that only the clicked item is visible and the rest isn't.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hansgohr/hnh5apkm/

Any suggestions would be great! :)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$('#left a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e){
    var target = this.hash
    $target = $(target);
    var others = $('#left a').not($(this)).attr('href')

        console.log(others)
    console.log(target)

    $( "#left" ).animate({ left: "50%" }, 800)
    $( "#right" ).animate({ right: "-50%" }, 800)
    $(target).animate({left: 0 }, 800)
    $(others).css("opacity", "0")

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Firstly move the preventDefault to top of the code since any error in the code will then skip the preventDefault. Then use .not(this)

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to js in general. So I updated the fiddle and it's almost working, but somehow only between content1 and content2, the third one is not selected within "others"

https://jsfiddle.net/hansgohr/hnh5apkm/2/

Comment: Ok I was definitly thinking too much in the wrong direction. I simply set the opacity from everything but the target to "0". Now it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#left a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var target = this.hash
   $target = $(target);
   $('.outer-left').css({"opacity": "0", "left": "-50%"})
   $( "#left" ).animate({ left: "50%" }, 800)
   $( "#right" ).animate({ right: "-50%" }, 800)
   $(target).css("opacity", "1").animate({left: 0 }, 800)
});
```